# My docker volume with option :default don't push container data

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I want to use a volume for my container and I want that during creation, the container pushes its contents onto my local machine so that my vuejs is present without doing docker-cp or COPY in my dockerfile but I can't do it not despite the :default option in the volume

My docker-compose file is like that :

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  Web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.web.dev
    image: nginx
    tty : true
    volumes:
        - ./shared/project:/var/www/html/project:default
    ports:
      - 5002:3000
```

My Dockerfile is like that:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN npm install -g @vue/cli
RUN vue create project -d
WORKDIR /var/www/html/project
```

Comment: Where is the `:default` option documented? https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Comment: If you're trying to build an environment where the application code lives only on the host, what benefit do you get from running the Node interpreter in an isolated container?  Can you just install Node on the host, and skip Docker entirely?

Comment: In fact I found this on a tutorial but I know that this option does not exist in the doc for the volumes.
My goal is to be able to connect my IDE to my remote machine to make my modifications and synchronize them with my container but when I mount my container for the first time if my volume directory on my machine is empty, my container writes to this directory . When I launch my docker-compose with my volume, I lose the init done by vuejs

Comment: That tutorial is not based on any docker reality that I know of. I'd file a bug report on the tutorial.